# in eclipse,how to conver a Project to a Java Project?

Tags: java, eclipse

i know i can change ".project" file in project path,

but i want to know how to do it in eclipse IDE? Is it possible?

thanks for watch :)

Comment: ChrisH is right, that's the answer.

Comment: thanks ChrisH,please answer this question,and i'll appect it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but is it that you can't view it properly? Is it filtered out of your view? You can change the filters in the Package Explorer view or switch to the Navigator view and you should see it there. Double click and you can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the project in the Package Explorer > Configure > and see if there is a add Java support.

Typically this is how you add support for other languages to the project, for example javascript, php, etc.